# Putting graphs with sin/cos waves in my Activity

Tags: android, graph

I'm currently developing an Android application which needs to receive data from a bluetooth device, and then display it. Some of this data comes in the form of sin/cos waves, and needs to be graphed.

Does anyone know how to add graphs to my Activity? The graph should be blank initially, then the user can choose from 12 different signals to graph.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a graphing library that was built for android.

Google also provides the [Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) that will generate png's for you which you can then show in an ImageView

I think both are capable of making line graphs. You'd just have to generate the data that will represent a sin/cos wave and pass it in to the chart engine.

Comment: I'm very new to android, and just came back to this post as I've come to the point in my project where this needs to be implemented. It turns out I don't even need to graph sine/cosine waves, but just datapoints which make up the wave. achartengine seems to be the solution, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Do you know anywhere I can find a simple tutorial for it?

Comment: For tutorials, see the answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828616/can-any-one-suggest-me-some-good-tutorials-on-achartengine-for-android-developme